# How to fix Tika server 413 entity too large error

Tags: apache-tika

I want to use Tika server to extract text from pdfs using POST request. However, when the size of the PDF is too large, it will appear 413 Entity too large error. How can I increase the size?

My request is like this:

```
curl -F upload=@price.xls URL http://localhost:9998/tika/form
```

Comment: Try one of the Apache Tika URLs which takes the file directly, without messing around with a form upload?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the pdfbox to split the document per pages